# Automatically insert records to the database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, dynamic

Good day, guys. I have a web application that is used for monthly inventories. I'm using java and MySQL. I'm able to insert and update a new record to the database. These monthly inventories can be viewed using jsp tables. The records are filtered by classifications and month-year. Every month contains a lot of same records and only differs to the number of inventory items and its price. Because of this, I want to make an automatic insertion of records in the database based from the records of the previous month.

Basically, what I want to do is to automatically fetch the records/items of the previous month and make a new copy to the database with an updated date based from the system date. This will be done every time the system date reaches a new month. Is this possible? If yes, can you suggest solutions on how I can achieve this? If not, can you suggest other alternative solutions? Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

I've made an extra button in my JSP that calls a servlet when clicked. This automatically generates a copy of records of the previous month. I used the INSERT ... SELECT query to do this. Now, I want make it like a scheduled task so that it automatically generates a copy of records without clicking a button. The records will be generated every time the system date changes the month and date. I've read about cron jobs but I don't really know how to apply it in my web application. I'm only using jsps and servlets in windows. Can anyone suggest How I can achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look up the `INSERT ... SELECT` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a cron job with you php file, assuming all the data will be passed from periodicity you can set your cron job up like so, if your not familiar at all with cron jobs [here's](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800) a good tutorial to get you going :

```
01 04 1 1 1 /var/www/somedirectory/somephpfile.php
```

just change the somedirectory/somephpfile.php to where your file is saved.

there's multiple different Cron codes you can use [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

heres a breakdown of the code i wrote above

```
01 04 1 1 1
```

this is your timing, starting from the first number:

1.minute (0-59)
2.hour (0-23)
3.day of month (1-31)
4.month (1-12)
5.day of week(0-6) starting from Sunday

Then the last part of the code:

```
/var/www/somedirectory/somephpfile.php
```

This is just the location of your file that you want to be executed automatically

if you need any more just ask =)

Comment: This would be better as a comment.

Comment: @Azar he didn't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: yes sorry i would have =)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie and I don't know how to do that. Can you give me some examples to do that?

Comment: @noahnu The reason for the rep restriction on comments is NOT so that new users can post their comments as answers instead.

Comment: @rocky im working on an example now for you

Comment: @DavidWallace Well, now he knows. As he has now stated, he is working on making this an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Right.  So what he should do is post an answer WHEN he has one.

Comment: @DavidWallace it would be far simpler for him to simply edit this post when it is ready, rather than deleting the answer, rewriting it as a comment and then making another answer afterwards. Welcome to SO Matt!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Ondkloss I just updated it to a proper answer i didnt mean to upset i was just giving a suggestion

Comment: Thank you @MatthewGalbraith! I'll try your suggestion. Btw, does cron job can also be used in a jsp?

Comment: Matthew, good answer, +1.  Sorry, I didn't mean to give you a hard time.  It was noahnu's comment that I was objecting to; not your answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks david! I try my best i didnt want to annoy anyone hehe and rocky i'm not sure how to go about it with jsp, i will look for you though and if i find anything ill get back to you. It is possible i'm just not sure how.